# Text mining on string dates from fuzzy example

Tags: python, date, parsing, extract

I'm a bit stuck with proceeding with the custom function that would be able to parse in any given language, with a set of rules that would be able to identify and parse months and years including some special cases (that I will show).

Input data:

```
dates_eg = [["Issued Feb 2018 · No Expiration Date"], ["Oct 2021 - Present"],
            ["Jan 2019 - Oct 2021 · 2 yrs 10 mos"], ["1994 - 2000"], ["Sep 2010 – Sep 2015 • 5 yrs"],
            ["Nov 2019 – Present"], ["Sep 2015 – Mar 2017 • 1 yr 6 mos"], ["Apr 2019 – Present • 2 yrs 8 mos"],
            ["Issued: Aug 2018 · Expired Aug 2020"], ["Mar 2017 - Dec 2017 · 10 mos"],
            ["May 2021 - Present · 9 mos"]]
```

**NOTE:** No API translation should be used. Instead of it, I've created a list of FLAG words (in certain languages) and STOPWORDS that would be able to identify all the cases.

- Present, Issued, Expired, No Expiration Date -> all of these four keywords/stopwords would be identified through the lists (see underneath).

Current functions work workflow:

e.g. **"Issued Feb 2018 · No Expiration Date"**

1. Firstly, algorithm named "raw_dates_extractor" is separating the start date ('Issued Feb 2018') and the end date ('No Expiration Date') with a separator ' · '
2. Secondly, clean_extract_dates algorithm is identifying 'Issued' and gets rid of it

All the aforementioned resulting in:

```
{'Start_date_raw0': 'Feb 2018', 'Start_date_raw1': 'Oct 2021', 'Start_date_raw2': 'Jan 2019', 'Start_date_raw3': '1994', 'Start_date_raw4': 'Sep 2010', 'Start_date_raw5': 'Nov 2019', 'Start_date_raw6': 'Sep 2015', 'Start_date_raw7': 'Apr 2019', 'Start_date_raw8': 'Aug 2018', 'Start_date_raw9': 'Mar 2017', 'Start_date_raw10': 'May 2021', 'End_date_raw0': 'No Expiration Date', 'End_date_raw1': 'Present', 'End_date_raw2': 'Oct 2021', 'End_date_raw3': '2000', 'End_date_raw4': 'Sep 2015', 'End_date_raw5': 'Present', 'End_date_raw6': 'Mar 2017', 'End_date_raw7': 'Present', 'End_date_raw8': 'Aug 2020', 'End_date_raw9': 'Dec 2017', 'End_date_raw10': 'Present'}
```

However, the desired output would go further by extracting/identifying years, months, and stopwords/flag words (like 'No Expiration Date', 'Present' would be flagged as 'ONGOING' = 1 otherwise 0.

From the first initial raw example:

```
"Issued Feb 2018 · No Expiration Date" would be:
```

Desired result:

```
     {'start_year': 2021, 'start_month': "Apr", 'end_year': None,
                             'end_month': None, 'is_on_going': True})
```

Complete Code attempt:

*Lists with Expired, Issued, No Expiration Date, Present*

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# "Present" word in all  language combination
present_all_lang = ["současnost", "I dag", "Heute", "Present", "actualidad", "aujourd’hui", "वर्तमान"
                                                                                            "Saat ini", "Presente",
                    "現在", "현재", "Kini", "heden", "Nå", "obecnie", "o momento"
                                                                  "Prezent", "настоящее время", "nu", "ปัจจุบัน ",
                    "Kasalukuyan", "Halen", "至今", "現在"]

# "Issued" word in all language combination
issued_all_lang = ["Vydáno", "Udstedt", "Ausgestellt", "Issued", "Expedición", "Émise le", "नव॰", "Diterbitkan"
                                                                                                  "Data di rilascio",
                   "発行日", "발행일", "Dikeluarkan", "Toegekend", "Utstedt", "Wydany", "Emitido em"
                                                                                  "Дата выдачи", "Utfärdat", "ออกเมื่อ",
                   "Inisyu", "tarihinde verildi", "颁发日期", "發照日期"]

# "No experience date" in all language combination
no_experience_all_lang = ["Bez data vypršení", "Ingen udløbsdato", "Kein Ablaufdatum", "No Expiration Date",
                          "Sin fecha de vencimiento", "Sans date d’expiration", "समाप्ति की कोई तारीख नहीं",
                          "Tidak Ada Tanggal Kedaluwarsa", "Nessuna data di scadenza", "有効期限なし"
                                                                                       "만료일 없음",
                          "Tiada Tarikh Tamat Tempoh", "Geen vervaldatum" "Ingen utløpsdato",
                          "Brak daty ważności", "Sem data de expiração", "Без истечения срока действия"
                                                                         "Inget utgångsdatum", "ไม่มีวันหมดอายุ",
                          "Walang Petsa ng Pagtatapos"
                          "Sona Erme Tarihi Yok", "长期有效", "永久有效"]

# "Expired" in all lang
expires_all_lang = ["Vyprší", "Udløbet", "Gültig bis", "Expired", "Vencimiento", "Expire le",
                    "को समाप्त हो गया है", "Kedaluwarsa", "Data di scadenza", "有効期限", " 만료됨", "Tamat Tempoh",
                    "Verloopt op", "Utløper", "Wygasa", "Expira em", "A expirat la", "Срок действия истек",
                    "Upphörde att gälla", "หมดอายุเมื่อ", "Mag-e-expire sa", "tarihinde süresi bitiyor", "有效期至", "過期"]
# colon my appear get rid of it!
```

```
def raw_dates_extractor(list_of_examples: dates_eg) -> dict:
    raw_start_date, raw_end_date, merged_start_end_dates = {}, {}, {}
    for row, datum in enumerate(list_of_examples):
        date_splitter = re.split("[·•–-]", datum[0])

        raw_start_date[f'Start_date_raw{row}'] = date_splitter[0].strip(' ')
        raw_end_date[f'End_date_raw{row}'] = date_splitter[1].strip(' ')
        merged_start_end_dates = raw_start_date | raw_end_date
    return merged_start_end_dates
```

output:

```
raw_dates_extractor(dates_eg)
{'Start_date_raw0': 'Issued Feb 2018', 'Start_date_raw1': 'Oct 2021', 'Start_date_raw2': 'Jan 2019', 'Start_date_raw3': '1994', 'Start_date_raw4': 'Sep 2010', 'Start_date_raw5': 'Nov 2019', 'Start_date_raw6': 'Sep 2015', 'Start_date_raw7': 'Apr 2019', 'Start_date_raw8': 'Issued: Aug 2018', 'Start_date_raw9': 'Mar 2017', 'Start_date_raw10': 'May 2021', 'End_date_raw0': 'No Expiration Date', 'End_date_raw1': 'Present', 'End_date_raw2': 'Oct 2021', 'End_date_raw3': '2000', 'End_date_raw4': 'Sep 2015', 'End_date_raw5': 'Present', 'End_date_raw6': 'Mar 2017', 'End_date_raw7': 'Present', 'End_date_raw8': 'Expired Aug 2020', 'End_date_raw9': 'Dec 2017', 'End_date_raw10': 'Present'}
```

```
def clean_extract_dates(input_dictionary: dict, aggregate_stop_words: list):
    container_replica = {}
    for date_element in input_dictionary:
        query_req = input_dictionary[f'{date_element}']
        if ":" in query_req:
            query_req = query_req.replace(":", "")
        if "." in query_req:
            query_req = query_req.replace(".", "")
        stopwords = aggregate_stop_words
        query_words = query_req.split()
        result_words = [word for word in query_words if word not in stopwords]
        end_result = ' '.join(result_words)
        container_replica[f'{date_element}'] = end_result
    return container_replica
```

output:

```
clean_extract_dates(raw_dates_extractor(dates_eg), aggregate_lists)
{'Start_date_raw0': 'Feb 2018', 'Start_date_raw1': 'Oct 2021', 'Start_date_raw2': 'Jan 2019', 'Start_date_raw3': '1994', 'Start_date_raw4': 'Sep 2010', 'Start_date_raw5': 'Nov 2019', 'Start_date_raw6': 'Sep 2015', 'Start_date_raw7': 'Apr 2019', 'Start_date_raw8': 'Aug 2018', 'Start_date_raw9': 'Mar 2017', 'Start_date_raw10': 'May 2021', 'End_date_raw0': 'No Expiration Date', 'End_date_raw1': 'Present', 'End_date_raw2': 'Oct 2021', 'End_date_raw3': '2000', 'End_date_raw4': 'Sep 2015', 'End_date_raw5': 'Present', 'End_date_raw6': 'Mar 2017', 'End_date_raw7': 'Present', 'End_date_raw8': 'Aug 2020', 'End_date_raw9': 'Dec 2017', 'End_date_raw10': 'Present'}

aggregate_lists = issued_all_lang + no_experience_all_lang + expires_all_lang
saved_dictionary = clean_extract_dates(raw_dates_extractor(dates_eg), aggregate_lists)
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: to preserve the order of the dictionary "Start_date_raw0", "Start_date_raw1" etc. I would probably further have to use conditions and function startswith("Start_date_raw") to mody the dictionary values in a way that I can further split by whitespaces, from which I will have to use regex to extract the 4digit number, also the same 4digit number has to be deleted from it, so that the remainder would be "months". It is so many ways of accessing and converting, is there any more elegant way? Please check the current output and the desired one to understand where am I exactly.

Comment: check OrderedDict in Python and dateutil here: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#parse-examples . dateutil can parse weird date into python datetime object